# Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, variables

Probably it's easy but I can't figure it out. I have this code:

```
var myNewHref = "#"+jQuery(this).attr('id');
jQuery(this).attr('href', myNewHref);
jQuery(this).attr("id", "");
```

In the first line I create new variable based on id of element. In second line I add a href property with myNewHref variable. In the third line I set id to be empty. The problem is that if I set my id to be empty it also changes myNewHref variable and makes it empty, but I want it to be still set with myNewHref. Besides action of clearing id takes place after I assigned it to my href. Anyone can help?

Comment: It shouldn’t do that; where does this code run? (Also, `jQuery(this).attr('id')` could just be `this.id`. Similarly, use `this.href = myNewHref` and `this.id = ""`. jQuery is *usually* simultaneously unnecessary and more complex than the equivalent DOM API.)

Comment: Are you sure that is what is happening? That doesn't seem right, and [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/px8pb/) confirms your code works fine. Also, like others have mentioned jQuery isn't necessary for the tasks you are performing (though unless there is more context, that isn't causing your issue either).

Comment: Thanx for answers. Now, after your responses I know why this is happening. This part of code is inside of jQuery(window).resize(function(){ here is the code }) function. So when I change the size of browser id is changing with every new dimensions of window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to work just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/4y2HM/4/

```
<a href="#" id="test">hello</a>

<script>
    $('#test').click(function(){
        var myNewHref = "#"+$(this).attr('id');
        $(this).attr('href', myNewHref);
        $(this).attr("id", "");
        alert("href: " + $(this).attr('href'));
        alert("id: " + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm [unable to replicate your issue](http://jsfiddle.net/4y2HM/5/) unless I run the code more than once. To clear the ID correctly, however, you can simply use:

```js
this.id = null;
```

You need to ensure that that code isn't run more than once. If your code *is* run more than once, then your ID will have already been removed and your `href` property will be set to just `#`. If your code is within an event handler based on that particular element you can make use of [jQuery's `one()` function](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to only handle that event once.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get rid of the `id` attribute, use this way:

```
jQuery(this).removeAttr("id");
/* Or */
this.removeAttr("id");
```

Or, if you want to nullify the `id`, you can use:

```
this.id = null;
```

Comment: That doesn’t really explain the behaviour described.

Comment: Depends on the use case. But better one.